# Excel VBA Search Button

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a text box and command button to search my entire workbook for a specific word or value.  For example, "3132" or "Work Instructions".  So far I am able to search the sheet that I am on but I cannot search the rest of the workbook.  Plus, some of the worksheets are hidden.  Any insight to this would be beneficial and help me out a ton!  I have listed my currect program below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Dim strFindWhat As String
    strFindWhat = TextBox1.Text

    On Error GoTo ErrorMessage

    Cells.Find(What:=strFindWhat, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False).Select
    Exit Sub

    ErrorMessage:
        MsgBox ("The data you are searching for does not exist")
End Sub
```

Have a good one!

Comment: Here's an example that searches the entire workbook by looping through each worksheet: http://excelvbaandmacros.blogspot.com/2011/09/search-stringvalue-in-entire-workbook.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through the array of worksheet objects in the `workbook.worksheets` collection.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this, which uses `FindNext` method while looping over the Sheets in the Workbook.

```
Sub FindLoopSheets()
Dim srchString$
Dim w As Integer
Dim wsName As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim fndRange As Range
Dim nxtRange As Range

srchString = Application.InputBox("Enter the value to search for", "Search Query")

If srchString = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "No value entered.", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
End If

For w = 1 To Sheets.Count
    With Sheets(w)
        wsName = .Name
        Debug.Print "Beginning search on " & wsName

        Set rng = .Cells.Find(What:=srchString, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Set fndRange = rng
            Do
                Set nxtRange = .Cells.FindNext(After:=fndRange)

                    Debug.Print Sheets(w).Name & "!" & nxtRange.Address
                    Set fndRange = nxtRange

            Loop Until fndRange.Address = rng.Address

        Else:
            Debug.Print srchString & " was not found on " & wsName

        End If
    End With
Next w

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 for going the extra mile.