# Excel vba search in column, select whole column

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in here. can anyone help me please?

Here is my sheet: In column A&B I have Apple, in column C&D I have Samsung, in column E&F HTC.

I would like to search the columns which include "HTC" word exactly. Since there are 2 of them, I want the select these 2 columns. Cut them and insert them into Column A&B.

So the order should be `HTC(ColA),HTC(ColB),Apple(ColC),Apple(ColD),Samsung(ColE),Samsung(ColF).`

I hope someone understands my question and hopefully answer it.

Comment: You would be better served by trying to do this, possibly by recording a macro, then coming back if you hit a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but you can use the match function to determine if a column contains a specific word:

```
Dim matchFound as Boolean
Dim c as Long
Dim rowNum as Long

For c = 5 to 6   'columns to be searched '
    matchFound = Not IsError(Application.Match("HTC", Columns(c), False))

    'Get the matching row number:
    If matchFound then rowNum = Application.Match("HTC", Columns(c), False))

        MsgBox "A match is found in Column " & c & ", Row " & rowNum, vbInformation
        'Put the values found in columns A or B '
        Cells(rowNum, c-4).Value = Cells(rowNum, c).Value
        matchFound = False
    End If
Next
```

Now that you now the row/column index of the matching cell, you can write it's value elsewhere, for example, place the values from columns 5 and 6 in to the columns 1 and 2: using this:

```
Cells(rowNum, c-4).Value = Cells(rowNum, c).Value
```

Etc.

If you expect more than one matching cell, then you'll need to use the `Find` and `FindNext` method, instead.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16423646/1467082