# Speed up loop in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I had some great help to get this search tool working in excel but I was wondering if there is room for speed improvement. I did some research and with what little I understand about VB for i = LBOUND(array) To UBOUND(array) seems most optimal. Would 'For Each' be faster? I am wondering if there is a way to isolate the records currently in the worksheet, or if it is already doing this with L/UBOUND? If it is, is there a way to do 'ignore special characters' similar to SQL? After adding screenupdating and calculation, I was able to shave about 10 seconds off of the total run time. And further I was using FormulaR1C1 for my search before this new loop and it would limit the amount of columns to search while being super fast.

```
Range("W2:W" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(R1C23,RC[-22]&RC[-21]&RC[-20]&RC[-19]&RC[-18]&RC[-17]&RC[-16]&RC[-15]&RC[-15]&RC[-14]&RC[-13]&RC[-12]&RC[-11]&RC[-10]&RC[-9]&RC[-8]&RC[-7]&RC[-6]&RC[-5]&RC[-4]&RC[-3]&RC[-2]&RC[-1])),0,1)"
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(23), 1) = 0 Then
Columns(23).Delete
```

Any help or recommendations are greatly appreciated.

```
    Sub FindFeature()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim shResults As Worksheet
    Dim vaData As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim sSearchTerm As String
    Dim sData As String
    Dim rNext As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim vaDataCopy As Variant
    Dim uRange As Range
    Dim findRange As Range
    Dim nxtRange As Range
    Dim ws As Range

    'Put all the data into an array
    vaData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value

    'Get the search term
    sSearchTerm = Application.InputBox("What are you looking for?")

    'Define and clear the results sheet
    Set shResults = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
    shResults.Range("A3").Resize(shResults.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).EntireRow.Delete

    Set uRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    vaData = uRange.Value
    vaDataCopy = vaData
    For Each v In vaDataCopy
        v = Anglicize(v)
    Next
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose (vaDataCopy)
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = vaDataCopy

    'Loop through the data

    Set ws = Cells.Find(What:=uRange, After:="ActiveCell", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        Set findRange = ws
        Do
            Set nxtRange = Cells.FindNext(After:=ws)
                Set findRange = nxtRange
        Loop Until ws.Address = findRange.Address

        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = vaData
                'Write the row to the next available row on Results
                Set rNext = shResults.Cells(shResults.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                rNext.Resize(1, uRange(vaData, 2)).Value = Application.Index(vaData, i, 0)
                'Stop looking in that row after one match
            End If
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Specialcells may add some improvement by letting you search through fewer cells http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Is the version of `Anglicize` being used the same as the one in the original version of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17427039/1 If so, there's a very unnecessary `Sheets("Results").Activate` line in there which might be having an effect on performance

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a must have feature. Unless there is a better way to do it. Maybe a msgbox and then a transfer after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, the execution speed here is severely hampered by the apparent requirement to operate on **every** cell in the range, and because you're asking about performance, I suspect this range may contain many thousands of cells.  There are two things I can think of:

**1. Save your results in an array and write to the Results worksheet in one statement**

Try replacing this:

```
'Write the row to the next available row on Results
Set rNext = shResults.Cells(shResults.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
rNext.Resize(1, UBound(vaData, 2)).Value = Application.Index(vaData, i, 0)
'Stop looking in that row after one match
Exit For
```

With a statement that assigns the value `Application.Index(vaData, i, 0)` to an array variable, and then when you're completed the `For i` loop, you can write the results in one pass to the results worksheet.

**NOTE** This may be noticeably faster if and only if there are many thousands of results. If there are only a few results expected, then exeuction speed is primarily affected by the need to iterate over every cell, not the operation of writing the results to another sheet.

**2.  Use another method than cell iteration**

If you can implement this method, I would use it in conjunction with the above.

Ordinarily I would recommend using the `.Find` and `.FindNext` methods as considerably more efficient than using the `i,j` iteration.  But since you need to use the `Anglicize` UDF on every cell in the range, you would need to make some restructure your code to accommodate. Might require multiple loops, for example, first `Anglicize` the `vaData` and preserve a copy of the non-Anglicized data, like:

```
Dim r as Long, c as Long
Dim vaDataCopy as Variant
Dim uRange as Range

Set uRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
vaData = uRange.Value
vaDataCopy = vaData
For r = 1 to Ubound(varDataCopy,1)
    For c = 1 to Ubound(varDataCopy,2)
        varDataCopy(r,c) = Anglicize(varDataCopy(r,c))
    Next
Next
```

Then, put the `Anglicize` version on to the worksheet.

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = vaDataCopy
```

Then, instead of the `For i =... For j =...` loop, use the `.Find` and `.FindNext` method on the `uRange` object.

Here is an [example of how I implement Find/FindNext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16423646/1467082).

Finally, put the non-Anglicized version back on the worksheet, again with the caveat that it might require use of `Transpose` function:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = vaData
```

Whil this still iterates over every value to perform the `Anglicize` function, it does not operate on every value a second time (`Instr` function). So, you're essentially operating on the values only once, rather than twice.  I suspect this should be much faster, especially if you combine it with the #1 above.

**UPDATE BASED ON OP REVISION EFFORTS**

After some comment discussion & emails back and forth, we arrive at this solution:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindFeature()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim shSearch As Worksheet:
    Dim shResults As Worksheet
    Dim vaData As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim sSearchTerm As String
    Dim sData As String
    Dim rNext As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim vaDataCopy As Variant
    Dim uRange As Range
    Dim findRange As Range
    Dim nxtRange As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim foundRows As Object
    Dim k As Variant

    Set shSearch = Sheets("City")
    shSearch.Activate
    'Define and clear the results sheet
    Set shResults = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
    shResults.Range("A3").Resize(shResults.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).EntireRow.Delete

    '# Create a dictionary to store our result rows
    Set foundRows = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Get the search term
    sSearchTerm = Application.InputBox("What are you looking for?")

    '# set and fill our range/array variables
    Set uRange = shSearch.UsedRange
    vaData = uRange.Value
    vaDataCopy = Application.Transpose(vaData)
    For r = 1 To UBound(vaDataCopy, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(vaDataCopy, 2)
        'MsgBox uRange.Address
            vaDataCopy(r, c) = Anglicize(vaDataCopy(r, c))
        Next
    Next

    '# Temporarily put the anglicized text on the worksheet
    uRange.Value = Application.Transpose(vaDataCopy)

    '# Loop through the data, finding instances of the sSearchTerm
    With uRange
        .Cells(1, 1).Activate
        Set rng = .Cells.Find(What:=sSearchTerm, After:=ActiveCell, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Set findRange = rng
            Do
                Set nxtRange = .Cells.FindNext(After:=findRange)
                Debug.Print sSearchTerm & " found at " & nxtRange.Address

                If Not foundRows.Exists(nxtRange.Row) Then
                    '# Make sure we're not storing the same row# multiple times.
                    '# store the row# in a Dictionary
                    foundRows.Add nxtRange.Row, nxtRange.Column
                End If

                Set findRange = nxtRange

            '# iterate over all matches, but stop when the FindNext brings us back to the first match
            Loop Until findRange.Address = rng.Address

            '# Iterate over the keys in the Dictionary.  This contains the ROW# where a match was found
            For Each k In foundRows.Keys
                '# Find the next empty row on results page:
                With shResults
                    Set rNext = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0). _
                                Resize(1, UBound(Application.Transpose(vaData), 1))
                End With
                '# Write the row to the next available row on Results
                rNext.Value = Application.Index(vaData, k, 0)
            Next
        Else:
            MsgBox sSearchTerm & " was not found"
        End If
    End With

    '# Put the non-Anglicized values back on the sheet
    uRange.Value = vaData
    '# Restore application properties
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    '# Display the results
    shResults.Activate
End Sub

Public Function Anglicize(ByVal sInput As String) As String

    Dim vaGood As Variant
    Dim vaBad As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sReturn As String
    Dim c As Range

    'Replace any 'bad' characters with 'good' characters

    vaGood = Split("S,Z,s,z,Y,A,A,A,A,A,A,C,E,E,E,E,I,I,I,I,D,N,O,O,O,O,O,U,U,U,U,Y,a,a,a,a,a,a,c,e,e,e,e,i,i,i,i,d,n,o,o,o,o,o,u,u,u,u,y,y", ",")
    vaBad = Split("Š,Ž,š,ž,Ÿ,À,Á,Â,Ã,Ä,Å,Ç,È,É,Ê,Ë,Ì,Í,Î,Ï,Ð,Ñ,Ò,Ó,Ô,Õ,Ö,Ù,Ú,Û,Ü,Ý,à,á,â,ã,ä,å,ç,è,é,ê,ë,ì,í,î,ï,ð,ñ,ò,ó,ô,õ,ö,ù,ú,û,ü,ý,ÿ", ",")
    sReturn = sInput

    Set c = Range("D1:G1")
        For i = LBound(vaBad) To UBound(vaBad)
            sReturn = Replace$(sReturn, vaBad(i), vaGood(i))
        Next i

    Anglicize = sReturn
    'Sheets("Results").Activate

End Function
```

Comment: Would it be easier to limit using the Anglicize to 2 columns? There are only 2 columns that that function needs to run on?

Comment: Appears to not help any. Your logic is spot on. My only issue is I am unsure how to implement it, haha. I will work on your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: @cbrannin yes, that would be easier. Still, if you have for example, 100,000 rows of data, that's 200,000 cells, so execution speed will still be slow, I think.

Comment: @cbrannin if you get stuck trying to implement my suggestsions, go ahead and revise your original question to include the new code that you are trying to use. I can take a look at it tonight and try to offer some more help.

Comment: OK. there is a problem with the first part of my #2 suggestion. I revised above. Let's start with that and then troubleshoot the `Find` loop.

Comment: Crashes here For r = 1 To UBound(varDataCopy, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(varDataCopy, 2)

Comment: typo. change `varDataCopy` to `vaDataCopy`.

Comment: It's not varData, the variable is vaData. My bad for not catching that. It clears that section and crashes at Set ws = Cells.Find()

Comment: Your `.Find` statement is wrong.  the `What:=` argument should be your search term, not a range variable. THe next line I see also has a typo where it says `Theh` instead of `Then`.  The rest of that loop probably needs some work, too.

Comment: The `After:=` argument is also wrong in that `.Find` statement. You can't pass a string literal like that.

Comment: I get an error 2042 on:  vaDataCopy(r, c) = Anglicize(vaDataCopy(r, c))

Comment: What is the value of `vaDataCopy(r,c)` when you get to this line?

Comment: Not exactly sure but when I hover over c = 25. Is there some other way to check this?

Comment: You can add a `MsgBox vaDataCopy(r,c)` as the preceding line, this will give you a message box with the value. Or, you can view the `vaDataCopy` and all of its items, as well as all other variables and their values in the `Locals` window (from the View menu | Locals Window).

Comment: This may also come in handy for future reference: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: MsgBox come back empty but in the Locals, I see (1 to 36)

Comment: (1 to 36) isn't the value. that's the size of the array `vaDataCopy`. This seems to be indicative of a one-dimensional array, which is not what I expect, given your previous `i,j` iteration (which implies a two-dimensional array). What is the `uRange.Address`?

Comment: I see how to read this. In the value area for vaDataCopy at (1,24) = "argentina" and at (1,25) = Error 2042 until (1, 36) . from msgbox:$A$1:$AJ$2