# Excel macros programming search

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Can you help me with edit macro? I would like to search on another sheet but I don't known what I do wrong. Sheet where I would like to search is "Díly".

```
Sub díly()

    Dim rngVis As Range
    Dim VisCell As Range
    Dim sFind As String

    sFind = InputBox("Naskenujte zákaznické císlo.")

    If Len(Trim(sFind)) = 0 Then Exit Sub    'Pressed cancel

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Intersect(Sheets("Díly").UsedRange, Sheets("Díly").Columns("A"))
        .AutoFilter 1, sFind
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngVis = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If rngVis Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox sFind & " Nenalezeno."
    Else
        For Each VisCell In rngVis.Cells
            MsgBox "Naskenované císlo: " & VisCell.Sheets("Díly").Cells(VisCell.Row, "A").Text & vbNewLine & _
                   "Vyhledáno: " & VisCell.Sheets("Díly").Cells(VisCell.Row, "B").Text
        Next VisCell
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error? At first - remove the non-latin characters from the code, like íč etc. If you want to show them in a message box, read them from a cell in Excel. Thus, try first with changing the characters and see if it works.

Comment: I search only on active sheet (active sheet where is a button is "kontrola") but I want search on sheet "Dily"

Comment: Can you try to change "Díly" to "Test" in both the code and your worksheet and give it a try again?

Comment: take a  look at the code here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422769/excel-vba-search-button it is generally what you are trying to do, without the bad practise of >on-error resume next<

Comment: I change it but to same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub díly()
    Dim rngVis As Range
    Dim VisCell As Range
    Dim sFind As String

    sFind = InputBox("Naskenujte zákaznické císlo.")

    If Len(Trim(sFind)) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Intersect(Sheets("Díly").UsedRange, Sheets("Díly").Columns("A"))
        .AutoFilter 1, sFind
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngVis = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If rngVis Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox sFind & " Nenalezeno."
    Else
        For Each VisCell In rngVis.Cells
            MsgBox "Naskenované císlo: " & VisCell.Text & vbNewLine & _
            "Vyhledáno: " & VisCell.Offset(, 1).Text
        Next VisCell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry me, but I don't get what problems you encountered with above code. please be more detailed